# hide/show a image in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to show/hide the image on clicking the hyperlink?

```
<script>
function getresource(id)
{
    if(id==4)
    {
       //show image
     }
    else if(id==5)
    {
         //hide image
     }

 } 
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getresource('4');">Bandwidth</a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getresource('5');">Upload</a>
<p align="center"> 
  <img id="img3" src="/media/img/close.png" style="visibility: hidden;" />
  <img id="img4" src="/media/img/close.png" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 21):

What image do you want to hide? Assuming all images, the following should work:

```
$("img").hide();
```

Otherwise, using selectors, you could find all images that are child elements of the containing div, and hide those.

However, i strongly recommend you read the Jquery docs, you could have figured it out yourself: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 7):

With image class name:

```
$('.img_class').hide(); // to hide image
$('.img_class').show(); // to show image
```

With image Id :

```
$('#img_id').hide(); // to hide image
$('#img_id').show(); // to show image
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [the `.css()` jQuery manipulators](http://api.jquery.com/css/), or better yet just call [`.show()`/`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) on the image once you've obtained a handle to it (e.g. `$('#img' + id)`).

BTW, you [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217/whats-the-purpose-if-any-of-javascript-in-event-handler-tags/23466#23466) write javascript handlers with the "javascript:" prefix.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function show_image(id)
{
    if(id =='band')
    {
       $("#upload").hide();
       $("#bandwith").show();
    }
    else if(id =='up')
    {
        $("#upload").show();
        $("#bandwith").hide();
    }
} 
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_image('bandwidth');">Bandwidth</a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_image('upload');">Upload</a>

<img src="img/im.png" id="band" style="visibility: hidden;" />
<img src="img/im1.png" id="up" style="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this just now. I ended up doing:

```
function newWaitImg(id) {
    var img = {
       "id" : id,
       "state" : "on",
       "hide" : function () {
           $(this.id).hide();
           this.state = "off";
       },
       "show" : function () {
           $(this.id).show();
           this.state = "on";
       },
       "toggle" : function () {
           if (this.state == "on") {
               this.hide();
           } else {
               this.show();
           }
       }
    };
};

.
.
.

var waitImg = newWaitImg("#myImg");
.
.
.
waitImg.hide(); / waitImg.show(); / waitImg.toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but it may be useful for those who are looking to show a .NET server side image using jQuery.

You have to use a slightly different logic.

So, $("#<%=myServerimg.ClientID%>").show() will not work if you hid the image using myServerimg.visible = false.

Instead, use the following on server side:

```
myServerimg.Style.Add("display", "none")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to hide upload img and show bandwidth img on bandwidth click and viceversa this would work

```
<script>

    function show_img(id)
    {
        if(id=='bandwidth')
        {
           $("#upload").hide();
           $("#bandwith").show();
        }
        else if(id=='upload')
        {
            $("#upload").show();
            $("#bandwith").hide();
        }
    return false;
     } 
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_img('bandwidth');">Bandwidth</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_img('upload');">Upload</a>
    <p align="center"> 
      <img src="/media/img/close.png" style="visibility: hidden;" id="bandwidth"/>
      <img src="/media/img/close.png" style="visibility: hidden;" id="upload"/>
    </p>
```