# Display all the data along with the image/icon when list is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

[image]

Above is the dropdown that when list is clicked, its value will be displayed in the field above (which is a button btw) together with the image. I've already achieved displaying the text but I cannot seem to display the image.  This is my markup below...

```
<button type="button" onclick="showbanks(); return false;" name="button" class="banknam btn dropdown-toggle center-right glyph form-control d-inline-block" data-toggle="dropdown-menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">广东</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-banknam">
    @foreach (array_slice($chosen_bank,0,5) as $index =>$bank)
        <li value="{{$bank}}" onclick="clickbanks(); return false;">
            <span class="bankimg d-inline-block"><img src="{{ asset($chosen_bankimg[$index]) }}" alt=""></span>
            <span class="bank_nam d-inline-block">{{ $bank }}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
```

...and my function...

```
function clickbanks(){
    $(".menu-banknam li").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".bb-container").find('.banknam').html($(this).text());
        return false;
    });
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: You could try jQuery [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide) and [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show)

Comment: @AniketG I'm afraid you need to do better than that.

Comment: Um what? *Do better*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide/show a image in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592870/hide-show-a-image-in-jquery)

Comment: @AniketG They're totally different. hide() is not an option. I'm sorry but perhaps you need to fully understand my question and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the entire content of the `li` instead of just the text.

e.g.

```
$(this).parents(".bb-container").find('.banknam').html($(this).html());
```

You are also assigning a new click event to the `li` each time you click on it.

You should remove the `clickbanks` function and instead assign the click event once when the document is ready. You'll also have to remove it from the `onclick` attribute of the `li`.

e.g.

```
$(function() {
  $(".menu-banknam li").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".bb-container").find('.banknam').html($(this).text());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks.